# Windows Service Application Multi-AZ High Availability in AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, windows-services

I have a C#.NET windows service application running on a windows EC2 in AWS. What is the best pattern to make this highly available using Multi-AZ (e.g. if the availability zone fails how will the 2nd windows service know to start up?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Windows Service runs for < 15mins convert it to a Lambda - that way it will scale in milliseconds, pay only for execution time used (not 24x7), forget about patching. If not, you could consider the Batch Service or lastly using EC2s.

You will want to automate the deployment of everything in AWS, either using the AWS SDK, the AWS CLI, AWS CDK or Cloud Formation.

CloudFormation is the easiest to setup, this example here creates a single EC2 in an ASG with a Min and Max equal to 1. This means if the EC2 instance goes down the ASG will detect that (it's called a Scale Event) and because the Minimum is 1 it will spin up another instance.

I've included a UserData example of downloading a powershell script that can install your service, it that takes too long I'd recommend you bake an AMI and use that in the CloudFormation (CFN) template. I'd recommend you upload this CFN template and try ad Terminate an Instance, a minute later the ASG will spin a new one up. The only way to is to delete the ASG to remove that one instance!

Replace "YourWindowsService" with your services name and specify the VPC:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: YourWindowsService deployment script

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: The environment we deploy to
    Type: String
    Default: 'nonprod'
    AllowedValues: ['nonprod','prod']
  KeyPairName:
    Description: >-
      Mandatory. Enter a Public/private key pair. If you do not have one in this region,
      please create it before continuing
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName'
    Default: YourKeyPairName
  Subnet1ID:
    Description: 'ID of the subnet 1 for auto scaling group'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
  Subnet2ID:
    Description: 'ID of the subnet 2 for auto scaling group'
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
  RemoteAccessCIDR:
    AllowedPattern: >-
      ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$
    ConstraintDescription: CIDR block parameter must be in the form x.x.x.x/x
    Description: Allowed CIDR block for external SSH access to YourWindowsServices IIS WS
    Type: String
    Default: 0.0.0.0/0
  AppName:
    Type: String
    Description: Application Name
    Default: "YourWindowsService"
  InstanceProfile:
    Type: String
    Default: YourIAMProvisioningProfileOrEc2FullAccess
  AMI:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Image::Id'


Mappings:
  EnvironmentToInstanceType:    
    nonprod:
      instanceType: t3.medium
    prod:
      instanceType: t3.large

  EnvironmentToVPC:
    nonprod:
      VPC: vpc-................
    prod:
      VPC: something.cant.be.null

  DisableTerminate:
    prod:
      YesorNo: 'false'
    nonprod:
      YesorNo: 'false'

Conditions:
  CreateNonProdResources: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, prod ]
  CreateProdResources: !Equals [ !Ref Environment, nonprod ]

Resources:
  YourWindowsServiceMainLogGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::LogGroup'
  SSHMetricFilter:
    Type: 'AWS::Logs::MetricFilter'
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Ref YourWindowsServiceMainLogGroup
      FilterPattern: ON FROM USER PWD
      MetricTransformations:
        - MetricName: SSHCommandCount
          MetricValue: 1
          MetricNamespace: !Join
            - /
            - - AWSQuickStart
              - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
  YourWindowsServiceAutoScalingGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup'
    Properties:
      LaunchConfigurationName: !Ref YourWindowsServiceLaunchConfiguration
      AutoScalingGroupName:  !Join
            - '.'
            - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
              - 'ASG'
      VPCZoneIdentifier:
        - !Ref Subnet1ID
        - !Ref Subnet2ID
      MinSize: 1
      MaxSize: 1
      Cooldown: '300'
      DesiredCapacity: 1
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: YourWindowsPCName
          PropagateAtLaunch: 'true'
          
  YourWindowsServiceLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'false'
      PlacementTenancy: default
      KeyName: !Ref KeyPairName
      ImageId: !Ref AMI

      SecurityGroups:
        - Fn::If: [CreateNonProdResources, !Ref YourWindowsServiceNonProdSecurityGroup, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]
        - Fn::If: [CreateProdResources, !Ref YourWindowsServiceProdSecurityGroup, !Ref "AWS::NoValue"]

      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref InstanceProfile
      InstanceType: !FindInMap [EnvironmentToInstanceType, !Ref 'Environment', instanceType]
      UserData:
        !Base64 |
          <powershell>
          #setup an install folder
          $path = "C:\temp\"
          If(!(test-path $path))
          {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
          }
          cd $path

          #using S3 (ie the AWS API) fetch the powershell install script and execute it
          $S3BucketName = "a-unique-bucket"
          $bootstrap = "install-env.ps1"
          $script = ($path + $bootstrap)
          Set-DefaultAWSRegion -Region ap-southeast-2
          Copy-S3Object -BucketName $S3BucketName -key $bootstrap -LocalFile ($path + $bootstrap)
          & $script
          </powershell>
          <persist>true</persist>
          <runAsLocalSystem>true</runAsLocalSystem>

  YourWindowsServiceNonProdSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Condition: CreateNonProdResources
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enables access to YourWindowsService
      GroupName: !Join
            - '.'
            - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
              - 'SG'
      VpcId: !FindInMap [EnvironmentToVPC, !Ref 'Environment', VPC]
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
        - IpProtocol: icmp
          FromPort: '-1'
          ToPort: '-1'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3389'
          ToPort: '3389'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
        - IpProtocol: udp
          FromPort: '3389'
          ToPort: '3389'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR

  YourWindowsServiceProdSecurityGroup:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup'
    Condition: CreateProdResources
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Enables access to YourWindowsService
      GroupName: !Join
            - '.'
            - - !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
              - 'SG'
      VpcId: !FindInMap [EnvironmentToVPC, !Ref 'Environment', VPC]
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
        - IpProtocol: icmp
          FromPort: '-1'
          ToPort: '-1'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '80'
          ToPort: '80'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '3389'
          ToPort: '3389'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
        - IpProtocol: udp
          FromPort: '3389'
          ToPort: '3389'
          CidrIp: !Ref RemoteAccessCIDR
```

Comment: I would double check if I have to use Lambda to replace my Windows service. EC2 instance might be a cheaper option if my code if running as a worker service. For example, If I run my 2gb memory allocated lambda code 24x7 in a cyclic execution, it will cost me approx. $86/month while an EC2 t3a.small will be $13.5/month. Lambda is great for event based execution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lock mechanism to prevent both instances to work on the same time.
Redis could be a good option, using https://github.com/samcook/RedLock.net

Answer (score 0):

An availability zone in AWS is a group of datacenters, it is unusual that all datacenters in an AZ can go down at the same. If you are okay with your EC2 windows instance to stay in single AZ,  you can setup [Auto Recovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-recovery-for-amazon-ec2/) on your EC2 instance. This will recover your EC2 instance on a healthy host in case the existing EC2 instance or the server is impaired.

In case you really want to go across the AZs in case of unlikely AZ level outage. You can setup [EC2 Auto scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html) with multiple AZs selected. You can choose to keep minimum and max instance count to 1. This way you are setting Auto Scaling to manage your EC2 instances across AZs while telling it to not create more than 1 instance at anytime. If your instance in existing AZ becomes unavailable and if the whole AZ where your instance is running becomes unavailable, the Auto Scaling service will launch your single instance in one of the other AZs. This is is an overkill for Windows Service though. This pattern makes sense for multiple Web Servers behind an Application Load Balancer. As I said, AWS AZs are group of multiple datacenters hence [Auto Recovery](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-auto-recovery-for-amazon-ec2/) is more than enough for a single EC2 instance.